# React Native how to get element position inside panresponder

Tags: javascript, react-native, gesture, panresponder

I'm trying to return the values of `.measure` but it seems the code inside can't interact without using a state, and so it keeps returning false. I'm trying to avoid using a state because I need the value inside my `PanResponder`

**Measure function returns false**

```
 const showRefPosition = assignedRef => {
    let maxHeight = false;

    assignedRef.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
      const maxY = SCREEN_HEIGHT - height;

      maxHeight = pageY - maxY < 40;
    });
    console.log("new maxHeight", maxHeight);

    return maxHeight;
  };
```

**What I'm trying to do:** is to get the elements position inside the `PanResponder`

**My problem**

I'm trying to get the elements position inside the `PanResponder`, but keep getting the wrong value (default value). Or the state inside the `PanResponder` doesn't update.

**PanResponder**

```
  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (event, gestureState) => {

        console.log("showRefPosition", showRefPosition(this.AnimatedRef));
        if (event.nativeEvent.pageY < 100) {

          pan.flattenOffset();
          Animated.spring(pan, {
            toValue: { x: 0, y: -600 },
          }).start();

          return false;
        }
        return Math.abs(gestureState.dy) > Math.abs(gestureState.dx * 3);
      },
```